# How do I extract the second and third columns from my CSV file with awk?

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk, csv

I'm using bash.  I have a CSV file with entries that look like this

```
102110089,54d8f511cc595d120048984b,57cc73366e58b7cc330083a7
102110091,54d8f511cc595d120048984d,57cc73366e58b7cc330083a8
102110093,54d8f511cc595d120048984e,57cc73366e58b7cc330083a9
```

I want to extract the second and third columns and put them into an SQL statement.  I thought this was the way to go ...

```
localhost:myproject davea$ awk '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='%s' where thirdparty_user_id='%s';", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' /tmp/Region1\ users.csv
awk: trying to access out of range field -1
 input record number 1, file /tmp/Region1 users.csv
 source line number 1
```

but I'm getting this "trying to access out of range field -1" error.  What's the proper syntax for extracting the second and third columns from my CSV file?

**Edit:** This is what's happneing in response to the answer given ...

```
localhost:myproject davea$ awk -F\, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id=\'%s\' where thirdparty_user_id=\'%s\'\;", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}'
>
```

**Edit 2** In response to the updated answer, here's my output.  Notice the word "update" is getting cut off ...

```
localhost:myproject davea$ awk -F, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'' where thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'';\n", $1,$3}' /tmp/myfile.csv
';date my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='102110089' where thirdparty_user_id='57cc73366e58b7cc330083a7
';date my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='102110091' where thirdparty_user_id='57cc73366e58b7cc330083a8
';date my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='102110093' where thirdparty_user_id='57cc73366e58b7cc330083a9
';date my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='102110107' where thirdparty_user_id='57cc73366e58b7cc330083b3
```

Comment: Set the delimiter to be `,`. By default is space so you have only one field visible from `awk`

Comment: Your data file has `\r\n` line endings, so do `tr -d '\r' < yourFile | awk ...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `awk` need to know the delimiter is `,`. So you should exec command on this way:

```
awk -F\, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id=\'%s\' where thirdparty_user_id=\'%s\'\;", $(NF-1),$(NF)}' /tmp/Region1\ users.csv
```

Also if the format of input file is consistent (three fields, you get 1st and 2nd) you can use `$1` and `$2`

Comment: Its still not printing things out exactly right.  Do I need to be escaping the apostraphes, like for instance, in this clause -- "set thirdparty_user_id='%s'"?

Comment: Yes, you should escape single quotas like this: `'` Will update my answer

Comment: there should be no need to escape comma. `-F, ` should be enough.

Comment: @Archemar, I will prefer to be on the safe site. One symbol more will not harm the script :)

Comment: @RomeoNinov, I think there still might be something not escaped quite right in your answer.  I cut and pasted it and it results in the shell printing out, ">", which I believe means its still expecting more input.  I edited my question with what I see.

Comment: @Dave, add at the end the input file (based on your edited question)

Comment: Even adding the input file the result is the same.  Something is fishy because normally I can autocomplete my filename by pressing tab but I can't seem to do that after putting in your command.

Comment: Try `{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'' where thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'';\n", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}` (the `'\''` sequence closes the outer quote string, inserts a literal quote, then reopens the outer quote string)

Comment: I get a series of errors, including "-bash: NF-2: command not found", "-bash: NF-1: command not found", and "awk: syntax error at source line 1".

Comment: @Dave are you omitting the outer quotes? the full command should be `awk -F, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'' where thirdparty_user_id='\''%s'\'';\n", $(NF-2),$(NF-1)}' /tmp/Region1\ users.csv`

Comment: Ah you are right!  THat gets past all the syntax errors.  However, the statement seems to be extracting the first and second columns and I wanted to extract the second and third columns.

Comment: @Dave, will update my answer

Comment: I tihnk you meant ot put your updated answer in comments combined with the "$(NF-1),$(NF)" syntax.  Maybe I'm wrong.  I edited my question to include the output.  Basically the word "update" is getting cut off.  Let me know if I'm reading you right.

Comment: Never mind -- that was just bad line endings causing all the madness.

Answer (score 1):

You need to tread carefully in this case since you have two layers of interleaving quotes:

```
        |-------------------------- 1 ------------------------|--2 --|------------- 3 ----------|--4 --|----- 5 ----|
awk -F, '{printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id='\'%s\'' where thirdparty_user_id='\'%s\'';\n", $2,$3}' yourcsvfile
```

Notice that regions 2 and 4 are white space (unquoted) and in there we insert our single quotes and %s strings. The regions 1,3,5 are balanced single quoted pairs. The regions 1..5 are contiguous. We are able to place %s in white space as is since they are not shell metacharacters like * ? $ [ or we'd have to escape them or place them in nonwhitespace regions like 3.

Another way is the via making available a quote via an awk variable:

```
awk -F, -v q=\' '{v2=q $2 q;v3=q $3 q;printf "update my_table_user set thirdparty_user_id=%s where thirdparty_user_id=%s;\n", v2,v3}' yourcsvfile
```

In this we first construct single-quote enclosed variables and them use them in our printf. I believe this is more user-friendly.